# What does "support" refer to in Android?

Tags: android

I am seeing:

on**Support**NavigateUp
**support**ShouldUpRecreateTask
onCreate**Support**NavigateUpTaskStack
onPrepare**Support**NavigateUpTaskStack

So what does it refer to?

Comment: You can get accurate info regarding **Support Library** from [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library) and for more packages details you should click [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey this support refer to backward compatibility

> Definition from tutorialspoint

**Support Library Features**

The Android Support Library package contains several libraries that can be included in your application. Each of these libraries supports a specific range of Android platform versions and set of features.

In order to effectively use the libraries, it is important to consider that which API level you want to target as each library supports different API level.

Following is a brief description of android support libraries and API level they support.

[tutorialspoint android_support_library](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_support_library.htm)